# plot a matrix as scatter plot and connecting largest point in each column

Tags: r, matrix, plot

I am newbie to R and stuck with this problem. 
I have matrix of integer value and I want to plot it as matrix where the size of points correspond the value of integer. So the larger is the value of one cell,the larger the point. at the end I want to connect the largest value of each column together using a line.

```
m <- matrix(sample(1:15,15),nrow=3,ncol=5)
dimnames(m)<-list(c("r1","r2","r3"),c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5"))

> m
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
r1  2  4  8  7  5
r2  1  9  6 13  3
r3 12 14 15 10 11
```

for example here my plot should contains 15 points where x-axis shows `c1,c2,c3,c4` and y-axis `r1,r2,r3`. And finally m(r3,d1),m(r3,c2),m(r3,c3),m(r2,c4) and m(r3,c5) should be connected. 
I tried using `matplot`:

```
 matplot(my[,-1],my[,1],type='p',pch=1)
```

but it doesn't produce what I want.

**UPDATE:**
I have a very spars matrix,so there are some columns with only zero values. In that case it should consider only one of them. The result of sven solution produces this:
[image]

**UPDATE2**

Thomas result:
[image]

Comment: What is the expected outcome if there is more than one value being identical to the maximum?

Comment: Which zero value should be considered?

Comment: doesn't important really.maybe the first max value in each col

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach with `reshape2` and `ggplot2`:

```
# The matrix (m):
   c1 c2 c3 c4 c5
r1  8  6  5  2 15
r2 12  9 10 13 14
r3  1  7  4 11  3


# transform data
library(reshape2)
dat <- melt(m, varnames = c("y", "x"))
dat <- transform(dat, max = ave(value, x, FUN = function(x) 
        replace(integer(length(x)),  which.max(x), 1L)))

# create plot
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = value)) +
  geom_line(data = subset(dat, as.logical(max)), aes(group = 1))
```

[image]

Comment: I get `Error in interaction(...) : object 'X2' not found` on the `transform` line.

Comment: @Thomas Did you use `dat <- melt(m)` before?

Comment: Yes, I ran the OP's data setup code and then yours all in a clean R session.

Comment: @Thomas I cannot reproduce this error. The command `melt(m)` creates a data frame with the column names `X1`, `X2`, and `value` on my system. I use `reshape2_1.2.2` and `R version 3.0.2`.

Comment: Strange. I have the same versions of the package and R (I'm on Windows). For me, the names on `dat` are: "Var1", "Var2", "value".

Comment: @Thomas This is really strange. I'm on Mac OS X. But the result should not depend on the OS.

Comment: @Thomas Now, I started a clean R session and obtain the same column names like you.

Comment: Thanks, but there is problem when there are two or more max value in column. Then it creates a line on that column. I am posting the plot and the answer

Comment: @SvenHohenstein can tell me where the value of 'value' in plot's legend comes from? I thought it comes from the value column of dat data frame, but it seems not. it happens the values on legends do not exist on dat column

Comment: @Moj The legend is named `value` because of the `value` column in `dat`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein I only have int value in my matrix,but the legend sometimes shows float value like 1.5. do you have any idea?\

Comment: @Moj Which values do you want to show in the legend?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a base graphics solution:

```
# reproducible data
set.seed(1)
m <- matrix(sample(1:15,15),nrow=3,ncol=5)
dimnames(m)<-list(c("r1","r2","r3"),c("c1","c2","c3","c4","c5"))
```

The plot:

```
e <- expand.grid(1:nrow(m), 1:ncol(m))
plot(e[,2], e[,1], cex=sqrt(m), xlim=c(0,6), ylim=c(0,4), pch=21, bg='black')
lines(1:ncol(m), apply(m,2,which.max), lwd=2)
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: @Thomas can you fix it in way that works for any matrix.

Comment: not working properly. I post the picture on my question

Comment: I am really interested to see the solution using base R.Thanks